# Power Series Representation of $x^3/(2-x)^3$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I don't need an answer, as this was a question I got wrong on a problem set, but could someone explain this?

So, we have to represent f(x)= $x^3$/$(2-x)^3$

My professor writes consider g(x) = $x^2/$(2-x)

I don't understand where she got this from?

Comment: It's not something she "got" (I don't think). It seems to be a hint for how to find a power series expansion for $f$.

Answer (score 4):

You are allowed to differentiate termwise a power series for all $u$ such that $|u|<R$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence.

Then starting with
$$
{1 \over (1-u)} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}u^{n}, \qquad|u|<1, \tag1
$$ **by differentiating twice**, you have successively
$$
{1 \over (1-u)^2} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nu^{n-1}, \qquad|u|<1,\tag2
$$ $$
{2 \over (1-u)^3} =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)u^{n-2}, \qquad|u|<1. \tag3
$$ Applying $(3)$ with $u=\dfrac x2$ gives
$$
{2 \over (1-\frac x2)^3} =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)\frac{x^{n-2}}{2^{n-2}}, \qquad \left|\frac x2\right|<1, \tag4
$$
multiplying out by $x^3$ and simplifying
$$
{16\:x^3 \over (2-x)^3} =\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n(n-1)\frac{x^{n+1}}{2^{n-2}}, \qquad \left|x\right|<2, \tag5
$$ or equivalently with a change of indice you get the power series representation

> $$
> {x^3 \over (2-x)^3} =\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(n-1)(n-2)\frac{x^n}{2^{n+1}}, \qquad \left|x\right|<2. \tag6
> $$